# Stopping the automatic snap to locator in Arcgis 10.0 reverse geocode

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network, reverse-geocoding, arcgis-api-wpf

I built a network application using arcgis 10.0 sdk for wpf. The application uses a locator of highway milestones to reverse geocode (and identify) the "flag" the user clicked on the map.

My Problem is that the locator somehow has a snapping effect - the "flag" moves to the nearest place the locator recognizes (The correct behavior I'm aiming for is the flag staying in the place where it was clicked and its place returned/not returned as a string based on the nearest place the locator recognizes being in the tolerance zone.

How can I disable this snapping behavior ( the automatic moving of the flag)?

Thanks in Advance.